# Possible to get the stored procedure call for debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net

While using Visual Studio 2010 for my ASP.NET website, we have code for a stored procedure call:

```
SqlDataAccess sqlDataAccess = new SqlDataAccess();

SqlParameter[] parameters =
{
    new SqlParameter("@R", rptType.Replace("'", "''")),
    new SqlParameter("@M", hybrDct["mod"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")),
    new SqlParameter("@C", hybrDct["CG"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")),
    new SqlParameter("@Ts$", hybrDct["TFields"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")),
};

sqlDataAccess.ProcName = "MyStoredProc";
sqlDataAccess.Parameters = parameters;
```

Is it possible to get the execute printed out for debugging purposes instead of finding out each individual SqlParameter and typing it in individually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like the following - everything goes through this and gets logged - you get the idea.

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a stored procedure with no return.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The number of records affected by stored proc.</returns>
public static int ExecuteStoredProc(string storedProcName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{        
    StringBuilder callDefinition = new StringBuilder();
    callDefinition.Append(string.Format("ExecuteStoredProc: {0} (", storedProcName));
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
    {
        callDefinition.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}", parameters[i].ParameterName, parameters[i].Value));
        if (i < parameters.Count - 1)
        {
            callDefinition.Append(",");
        }
    }
    callDefinition.Append(")";
    log.Debug(callDefinition.ToString());
    using (var ctx = ConnectionManager<SqlConnection>.GetManager(ConnectionProfile.ConnectionName))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, ctx.Connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                //log your param here
            }

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Executes a query and returns a dataset
/// </summary>
public static DataSet ExecuteQueryReturnDataSet(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        //implement the parameter logging here as in the above code sample as well

        log.Debug("Executing ExecuteQueryReturnDataSet() calling query " + query);
        using (var ctx = ConnectionManager<SqlConnection>.GetManager(ConnectionProfile.ConnectionName))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, ctx.Connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                    return dataSet;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - provided you dont want to do your logging , dbnull checks, etc there for any specific values.

Answer (score 1):

I usually run the SQL Server Profiler (assuming that this is your database) and can copy the complete query from the log.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SqlClient (which I assume you are using to implement SqlDataAccess, which I also assume is your own data access layer) does not directly expose the commands sent to the SQL Server. What I typically do inside my data access layer is log all commands in a format that can be executed in a query window.